# MySQL cookbook on Chef doesnt run twice

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm currently trying out chef - more precisely - to setup a simple lamp with it. My cookbook should contain apache2, mysql and php at sometime. Right now I'm stuck with mysql.

The cookbook I'm using: https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/mysql. My configuration is almost the same as on the cookbook guide page.

```rb
databag_secret = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret("/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret")
secrets_mysql = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("secrets", "mysql", databag_secret)

include_recipe "mysql::client"
include_recipe "mysql::server"

mysql_service 'default' do
  allow_remote_root false
  remove_anonymous_users true
  remove_test_database true
  #server_root_password secrets_mysql['mysql_root_pass']
  server_debian_password 'vagrantsuxx'
  action :create
end
```

Retrieving my secret from the data bag works just fine and the first run of my cookbook always passes. Whenever I try to run it a second time it get the following error:

```
[2014-07-22T14:32:01+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete

[2014-07-22T14:32:01+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-07-22T14:32:01+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 5 resources updated in 6.99007798 seconds
[2014-07-22T14:32:01+00:00] ERROR: mysql_service[default] (mysql::server line 20) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[install-grants] (/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_service_ubuntu.rb line 91) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /usr/bin/mysql -u root -pilikerandompasswords < /etc/mysql_grants.sql ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
---- End output of /usr/bin/mysql -u root -pilikerandompasswords < /etc/mysql_grants.sql ----
Ran /usr/bin/mysql -u root -pilikerandompasswords < /etc/mysql_grants.sql returned 1
[2014-07-22T14:32:01+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I wonder why that is. The passwords on /etc/mysql_grants.sql are somehow getting reset. Anyone else experienced this? What am I missing?

Comment: Is there anywhere in your cookbook that sets the password in /etc/mysql_grants.sql? Is there any more detail in chef-stacktrace.out?

Comment: As stated before - the little thing you see there is my whole config. I have not touched any other file besides some data bag JSONs. So my cookbook annot modify the password in mysql_grants.sql.

Comment: I have to admit I'm not that familiar with the `mysql_grants.sql` file. Does MySQL really store permissions in a plain file like that? So you check the contents of the file after each run and it's different after each run?

Comment: The stacktrace.out file is linked right here: http://pastebin.com/2NUsuLCb

Comment: Thanks for linking that, it's always good to rule out hidden problems. After the 2nd run, can you authenticate with MySQL manually? Or have the permissions been completely wiped/changed?

Comment: I can authenticate perfectly well with my password stored in the data bag on chef. If I change the root password to the dummy password of the mysql cookbook the procedure runs through without any errors at all. I've never noticed a mysql_grants.sql file so far when dealing with MySQL so I guess it's a chef / chef mysql cookbook thing.

Comment: Btw. I just came back to this issue and can happily tell you that it has been fixed by declaring the root password with node.default['mysql]['mysql_root_pass'] = XXX before including the recipe :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the password?

I can't see it in that configuration

secrets_mysql seems to be getting read in then I can't see it being operated on. It doesn't seem to be used in the base cookbook either so I'm not 100% convinced the password is getting into the provider to be loaded. I see it's commented out in your provider call there

The following shows how the password string is built up in the debian helper before it's used by the service provider

```
  def pass_string
    if new_resource.parsed_server_root_password.empty?
      pass_string = ''
    else
      pass_string = '-p' + Shellwords.escape(new_resource.parsed_server_root_password)
    end

    pass_string = '-p' + ::File.open('/etc/.mysql_root').read.chomp if ::File.exist?('/etc/.mysql_root')
    pass_string
  end
```

This is it then being used

```
        cmd << "#{pass_string} < /etc/mysql_grants.sql"
```

So the resource value is defined as follows

```
    def parsed_server_root_password
  return server_root_password if server_root_password
end
```

And that has a default of ilikerandompasswords.

What happens when you uncomments the line using the databag value?